# Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, observable

I want to do pooling from Angular 9/RxJs to a rest service returning a status every 5 seconds. The rest service is a tipical get simply returning the status from a transaction. The code bellow are based on few searchs around including some answers here in StackOver flow. I keep getting the error pasted bellow.

All answers I have found so far tell to import what I am already importing.

Any extra thing to check will be highly appreciated.

error:

```
core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.interval is not a function
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:37)
    at callHook (core.js:4686)
    at callHooks (core.js:4650)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4591)
    at refreshView (core.js:11814)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:11922)
    at tickRootContext (core.js:13391)
    at detectChangesInRootView (core.js:13425)
    at RootViewRef.detectChanges (core.js:15103)
    at ApplicationRef.tick (core.js:42712)
```

app.component.ts

```
//most relevant imports for this question
import { Observable, timer, interval, of } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, map, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [SseService],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  //polledTransacaoStatus$: Observable<string>;
  pollingData: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const status$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/extrato/1');

    this.pollingData = Observable.interval(5000) //the issue is here
      .switchMap(() => status$)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.pollingData.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using an old (deprecated) syntax to set up the observables.

Use this instead:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const status$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/extrato/1');

  this.pollingData = interval(5000)
    .pipe(switchMap((_: number) => status$))
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => console.log(data),
      (error: any) => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

[UPDATE]: to stop after 60 seconds

```js
this.pollingData = interval(5000)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((_: number) => status$),
    takeUntil(timer(60000)), // <= takeUntil will unsubscribe when timer emits  
  ).subscribe(
    (data: any) => console.log(data),
    (error: any) => console.log(error)
  );
```

Comment: Obrigado (thanks)! You answered my question! If you don't mind two last comments: (1) how to stop/unsubscribe after 60 seconds? (2) As a typical rule of thumb, do you think by using Observable.interval is a good approach when you just want to get the status from a transaction? I mean, there will be a post starting a transaction that is expected take normally around 30 seconds from Angular to BackEnd and then the above polling "asking" for the status every 5 seconds. Would you condider other than RxJs Observable.interval idea as more popular for such scenario?

Comment: (1) updated my answer to show how to unsubscribe; (2) a better approach would be using web sockets (the backend would notify the front end when it's done). But depending on how often you show this component, the current approach would be acceptable.

Comment: Good point. I miss a forum focused in architecture discussion. Somewhere I could discuss what is better, "implementation A" versus "implementaion B". If I post here a question like "what are the pro/against of implementing using 'websocket with backend notifying' and 'sse with interval pooling' for updating Angular of transaction request?" I am sure will be closed. When I asked a better approach I have pooling from frontend in mind. I believe websocket shouldn't be used for pooling a transcation status. You could use to push status which tends to infinite and are two ways (eg. chat dialog)

Comment: Well, for pulling from the frontend, I think your approach is ok. I've built something like that in an issue tracker app project, where I wished the comments to be updated to anyone with that issue active on the screen. The drawback is that you must implement some kind of server-side cache if you need this approach to scale. Without any caching scheme and with a single server, it works without any performance decrease when you have, at most, a tenth of users visualizing and commenting on the same issue (I'm considering here the database delay on each data retrieve).